# How to generate an index page for a specific tag link in a tag cloud?

Tags: javascript, html, tag-cloud

Failed to find an answer for this question, though it must be quite simple. I'm a beginner in web dev and will highly appreciate your help.

I want to make a tag cloud on a web site which i'm working on. It's a sort of diary when each page corresponds to some date. No CMS, my own coding (just for learning reasons). There are many solutions how to generate a cloud itself from the given list of words, but I'm stuck on the further step, i.e. tag links:

Should I create an index page for every tag 'manually' or is there some way to automate this process? I mean, should I write in html/css every tag-connected page, which would contain links to the other pages linked to a particular tag, or is it possible to code some template and then generate pages for each tag based on that template? I have some knowledge of javascript, python and very little of php (but ready and eager to learn more :).

What would you suggest? 
Thnx

Comment: A suggestion: create 1 page that takes an argument from the URL like this `www.example.com/tags/monday-blues` (pretty URL - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) or ´www.example.com/tags?tag=monday-blues`. On that page, tags, have code that fetches relevant data based on the URL parameter.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, @stubben! The most interesting part is about 'fetching relevant data' ) Does it mean that some kind of external file, a table (SQL? XML?) with URLs of pages and corresponding tags should be created and then my code inside 'tags.php' (?) should address this file to fetch data from and generate, as in your example, the actual `www.example.com/tags/monday-blues` page? Or can it be done without additional external files?

Comment: That depends on how your data is structured and saved. Are you using a database or files? The URL parameter is going to be used in a query. The query could be done on a database or file system or in code in the browser (javascript). 

Are you using a server side language like PHP or are you only using javascript in the front end?

Comment: If it's possible to implement this in javascript (ie to connect each page to a specific tag(s), then I'd prefer this to php. Can you give me some hint how it can be done? Maybe via storage?... It would be great if you also suggested some reading on queries and data structures for web dev. Thank you!

Comment: From the top of my mind, you should look at something like Isotope, http://isotope.metafizzy.co/. It might be what you are looking for in the sense of having tags and then filter content based on that.

About reading, I would start by defining a project, fx. create a todo list or inventory list. From there the questions will arise and then it will be more straight forward to ask questions to solve specific problems.